# SuiteCRM 7.3 - how do I add my own notification?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

The recently released SuiteCRM 7.3 has the ability to show desktop notifications and notifications on the site (in the header).

How can I add or trigger my own custom notifications through code?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tested this but you should be able to simply save a new Alert bean.

I.e.

```
$alert = BeanFactory::newBean('Alerts');
$alert->name = 'My Alert';
$alert->description = 'This is my alert!';
$alert->url_redirect = 'index.php';
$alert->target_module = 'Accounts';
$alert->assigned_user_id = '1';
$alert->type = 'info';
$alert->is_read = 0;
$alert->save();
```

The `action_add` method in `modules/Alerts/controller.php` provides an example.

Comment: I don't think alerts and notifications are exactly the same thing. i'm talking about the new desktop notification functionality in SuiteCrm 7.3.

Comment: @ElizabethMeyer By the looks of things you can add desktop notifications using the `jsAlerts` class in `include/javascript/jsAlerts.php`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create alert for user an example after save Leads record with the Logic Hooks

In file `custom\modules\Leads\logic_hooks.php` add the following string:

```
$hook_array['after_save'][] = Array(2, 'send alert to user', 'custom/modules/Leads/LogicHooks/SendAlert.php','LeadHooks', 'sendAlert');
```

Next step, create a folder and file in it `LogicHooks\SendAlert.php`
in the `custom\modules\Leads\LogicHooks\SendAlert.php` and add this class:

```
class LeadHooks{
    public function sendAlert($bean,$events,$arguments){
        $seedAlert = new Alert();
        $seedAlert->name = "New Lead";
        $seedAlert->description = "Lead assigned to yu";
        $seedAlert->assigned_user_id = $bean->fetched_row['assigned_user_id'];
        $seedAlert->is_read = 0 ;
        $seedAlert->type = "info" ;
        $seedAlert->target_module = "Leads";
        $seedAlert->url_redirect = "index.php?action=DetailView&module=Leads&record=".$bean>fetched_row['id']."&return_module=Leads&return_action=DetailView";
        $seedAlert->save();
    }
}
```

Its all for the rest modules, you should do the same.